# Media Scanner Is Scanning, But Not Refreshing (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, android-camera

I have a gallery app that also has camera functionality. After taking the photo, my On Activity Result calls for a media scanner to scan for the file. While it does scan for the file, and the LogCat reports the exact location of it, and it saves in the specified directory, but my gallery, and others such as Google Photos do NOT show the image until next reboot, or a long time has passed. What am I doing wrong?

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SETTINGS_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        MediaFragment content = (MediaFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(com.marlonjones.aperture.R.id.content_frame);
        if (content != null) content.reload();
        reloadNavDrawerAlbums();
    }
    if (requestCode == NEW_PICTURE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri uri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
            }
            if (uri == null && mCameraFileName != null) {
                uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFileName));
            }
            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("-mm-ss");
            String newPicFile = "PH" + df.format(date) + ".jpg";
            String outPath = "/sdcard/Aperture/" + newPicFile;
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{Uri.fromFile(new File (outPath)).toString()}, null,
                    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
}

 public void camera(MenuItem menu) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        int hasCameraPermission = checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        if (hasCameraPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("-mm-ss");

        String newPicFile = "PH" + df.format(date) + ".jpg";
        String outPath = "/sdcard/Aperture/" + newPicFile;
        File outFile = new File(outPath);
        mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
        Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PICTURE);
    }
     else {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("-mm-ss");

        String newPicFile = "PH" + df.format(date) + ".jpg";
        String outPath = "/sdcard/Aperture/" + newPicFile;
        File outFile = new File(outPath);
        mCameraFileName = outFile.toString();
        Uri outuri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outuri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_PICTURE);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Never hardcode paths**. Your code is incorrect for hundreds of millions of Android devices when used with secondary accounts. Use methods to get at filesystem locations. In your case, replace:

```
String outPath = "/sdcard/Aperture/" + newPicFile;
```

with:

```
File picFile=new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Aperture"), newPicFile);
```

Second, `scanFile()` takes an array of paths, not `Uri` values. Replace:

```
new String[]{Uri.fromFile(new File (outPath)).toString()}
```

with:

```
new String[]{picFile.getAbsolutePath()}
```

Comment: My Camera Intent also uses /sdcard/Aperture. it saves to it, but should I replace this as well?

Comment: @VirusThePanda: Yes, for the same reason. On Android 4.2+ tablets, and Android 5.0+ phones, there can be more than one user account. Each user gets its own locations for things like external storage, and their paths will differ.

Comment: Okay, in my camera intent, I used : `tring outPath = "/Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()/Aperture/" + newPicFile;` Would this be correct? Or should it be the exact same as your answer?

Comment: Now the file is not being created at all. Can you help with this? I have reverted the code back to it's original state so you can see it. This is the camera intent. (Look in the question. Edited)

Comment: @VirusThePanda: Well, you will have somewhat better luck if you use the same filename. `new Date()` will be different at different points in time, and so filenames based on `new Date()` will be different at different points in time. You set `mCameraFileName`, then ignore it `onActivityResult()` when you call `scanFile()`.

Comment: So instead of new date, use something like "ph Aperture.PNG"?

Comment: @VirusThePanda: You could do that. I meant, in `onActivityResult()`, use `mCameraFileName`, instead of generating a new filename. After all, by definition, nothing will be at that filename, as you just created it and the filename is time-dependent.